# Docker supervisor - unable to find supervisor.conf file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, supervisord, boot2docker

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/).

In that tutorial there is this step:

> Now let’s add a configuration file for Supervisor. The default file is called supervisord.conf and is located in /etc/supervisor/conf.d/.
>
> `COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf`
>
> Let’s see what is inside our supervisord.conf file.

But when I try to build my image I get this error:

```
Step 7 : COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
supervisord.conf: no such file or directory
```

Doesn't make any sense, that's what the tutorial told me to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place a `supervisord.conf` file with the contents provided in the tutorial into the same folder in which you put your `Dockerfile`.

The `COPY` instruction used in the `Dockerfile` does not specify an absolute path. It provides only the filename so the file is looked up in the root folder of your current build context. That is the folder where your `Dockerfile` is placed.

Answer (score -1):

There is no magic in docker, if you want to use supervisor, you must do in a Dockerfile what you would do on any Linux node when you install supervisor, and this includes copying some files to the right place.